# What is the correct Gaussian to use given that I know the true second moment and have one sample from the distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean, sample, moments

I have some random variable $X$ that is normal distributed. I know the second moment $s = \mathbb{E}[X^2]$ and have one sample x from the distribution. How can I get an unbiased estimate of the mean and variance? My current best idea is $\mathcal{N}(x,2(s - x^2))$ since $s - x^2$ would be a (biased?) estimate of the variance and since the mean is uncertain with the same variance as the distribution that should double the variance. Is there a better way?

Comment: Let $\mu=E[x]=E[X]$ and $\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}(x)= \operatorname{Var}(X) = s^2 - \mu^2.$  The answers leap out at you.

Comment: @whuber The problem is that I know neither $\mu$ nor $E[x]$ nor $E[X]$ and x is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$ with variance $\sigma^2$ but how can I get an unbiased estimate of $\mu^2$ or the variance?

Comment: An unbiased estimator of $\mu \sigma^2$ from a normal distribution is $\frac12(x^3-x\mathbb{E}[x^2])$ though this is not quite what you asked for

Comment: Because you know $s^2,$ any unbiased estimator of $s^2-\mu^2$ can be converted into an unbiased estimator of $\mu^2.$

Comment: @whuber Sure but how do I get an unbiased estimator of $s^2 - \mu^2$?

Comment: What is $E[x^2-s^2]$?

Comment: @whuber Well x^2 follows a scaled non-central chi-square distribution so the expectation of $x^2$ should be  $\sigma^2*(1+\mu^2)$ I think. So for $x^2 - s^2$ it is $(\sigma^2-1)\mu^2$.

Comment: You're overthinking this: all you need to do is propose a statistic -- which is a function of $x$ -- whose expectation equals the parameter you are estimating.

Comment: @whuber But how do I do that? $\mathbb{E}[x^2] \neq \mu^2$

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured out a partial answer to my question: I think it would be good to approach this from a Bayesian perspective where we have a prior over normal distributions given the second moment and then calculate the posterior over prior distribution using the likelihood of the observed sample given the model. Finally we can integrate over the posterior to get the (unnormalized) PDF of our believe distribution about what the next sample would look like.

So we can parametrize our normal distribution model by the standard deviation $d$. Given we know the second moment $s$, the mean will be $\sqrt{s - d^2}$. Then we can derive the Jeffreys prior like this:
[image: Deriving the Jeffreys prior]

If I now plot the unnormalized PDF of our believes, it looks a lot like a mixture of two Gaussians:
[image: Unnormalized PDF]

Splitting up Jeffreys prior and integrating the summands seperately seems to confirm this hypothesis:
[image: First component]
[image: Second component]

However, I have not been able to analytically verify this or compute the parameters of the mixture. If someone is able to do that I would be happy to accept that as an answer!